# How to pass properties to Rollback custom action in wix?

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have a pair of custom actions one that moves some deprecated files to a temp directory and another one that runs if the installer rolls back to put them back. I have to use a custom action because the previous installer was installshield.

Below are my custom actions:

```
<CustomAction Id="DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles" BinaryKey="FileSearchCA" DllEntry="DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

    <CustomAction Id="RestoreDeprecatedFiles"
                  BinaryKey="FileSearchCA"
                  DllEntry="RestoreDeprecatedFiles"
                  Execute="rollback"
                  Return="ignore"
              />

    <CustomAction Id="SetRollbackData" Property="RestoreDeprecatedFiles" Value="RootDir=[DEPRECATEDFILESROOTDIR];TempDir=[DEPRECATEDTEMPORARYDIR]" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore"/>
```

Below is the scheduling of these actions:

```
            <Custom Action="SetRollbackData" After="DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles">
            OLD_VERSION_FOUND OR                        <!--Run if we are doing a major upgrade (msi -> msi).-->
            REMOVEINSTALLSHIELD
        </Custom>
        <Custom Action="DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles" Before="InstallFinalize">
            OLD_VERSION_FOUND OR                        <!--Run if we are doing a major upgrade (msi -> msi).-->
            REMOVEINSTALLSHIELD                         <!--Run if we are upgrading installshield instance.-->
        </Custom>
        <Custom Action="RestoreDeprecatedFiles" After="InstallInitialize"/>
```

Then in the log I get:

```
MSI (s) (04:74) [11:31:22:162]: Doing action: DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles
Action 11:31:22: DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles. 
Action start 11:31:22: DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles.
MSI (s) (04:3C) [11:31:22:171]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI8804.tmp, Entrypoint: DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI8804.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
Calling custom action FileSearchCA!FileSearchCA.FileSearchCA.DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles
Starting UserAdmin delete deprecated files Custom Action.
MSI (s) (04!50) [11:31:22:376]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DEPRECATEDFILESROOTDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Program Files\Duck Creek Technologies\ExampleUserAdmin\bin'.
MSI (s) (04!50) [11:31:22:380]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DEPRECATEDTEMPORARYDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Users\LMUser\AppData\Local\Temp\t3n1evfp.dwa'.
Action ended 11:31:22: DeleteUserAdminDeprecatedFiles. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (04:74) [11:31:22:429]: Doing action: SetRollbackData
Action 11:31:22: SetRollbackData. 
Action start 11:31:22: SetRollbackData.
MSI (s) (04:74) [11:31:22:437]: Note: 1: 2723 2: SetRollbackData 
DEBUG: Error 2723:  Custom action SetRollbackData specifies unsupported type
```

Any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot I got it fixed.

I had to change:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetRollbackData" Property="RestoreDeprecatedFiles" Value="RootDir=[DEPRECATEDFILESROOTDIR];TempDir=[DEPRECATEDTEMPORARYDIR]" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore"/>
```

To:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetRollbackData" Property="RestoreDeprecatedFiles" Value="RootDir=[DEPRECATEDFILESROOTDIR];TempDir=[DEPRECATEDTEMPORARYDIR]" />
```

Comment: I know this is old, but its sad when you have to answer your own question.  Good work, and thanks for documenting!